# Parse bytecode from string?

Tags: ruby

I have a situation where I'm receiving strings for bytecode that look like this:

```
"\\x00\\x00\\xff\n"
```

Where the `\` in the bytecode has been escaped. I'd really like to take a string like this one:

```
"\\x00\\x00\\xff\n"
```

and get the bytes from it like I would for this string like this:

```
"\x00\x00\xff".bytes # => [ 0, 0, 255 ]
```

How can I better handle that string?

It's sent over UDP from another system so I really only have access to it like a messy escaped string like it arrives.

Comment: UDP makes no difference to the format of the string. It makes a heck of a lot of difference in delivery reliability, but the content is guaranteed to be the same as what was sent.

Comment: I think I was trying to defend against the inevitable comment of "why do you have a string like that in the first place", so I put my excuse out front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a more elegant way, but this should get you started:

```
a= "\\x00\\x00\\xff\n"
a.scan(/\\x([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])/).flatten.collect{|x| x.to_i(16)}  # =>  [ 0, 0, 255 ]
```

`to.i(16)` will convert from a hex string to a decimal.

It seems like you're looking to interpolate the escape sequences.

I know that this can be done using eval but **don't**.  I think it can be done via YAML as well.

```
eval("\"#{a}\"").strip.bytes.to_a # => [ 0, 0, 255]  # don't use this.
```

Just hoping to inspire better answers here.